# C++ Nonstatic member referencing must be relative to specific object

Tags: c++, class, reference, static, member

This Complex Number program is supposed to take three arguments from a txt document, the first to indicate whether the subsequent two are numbers in polar or rectangular form, and output every complex number given in both rectangular and polar form. Both the header file and source code are shown here. The txt document is in the following format:

```
p 50 1.2
r 4 0.8
r 2 3.1
p 46 2.9
p 3 5.6
```

Without declaring the int inputfile() function as static within the class declarations, the build gives an error 'illegal call of non-static member function'.

With the static declaration of the function (shown below), the build gives errors referring to the class members Pfirst, Psecond, Rfirst and Rsecond inside function definition inputfile(), being 'illegal references to non-static members'.

The member declarations cannot then be made static as well because the class would not be able to initialise the parameters within the constructor.

How can I bypass this 'static' problem?

```
#define Complex_h

class Complex
{
    char indicator;

    const double pi;


public:
    double Pfirst, Psecond, Rfirst, Rsecond;
    Complex(char i = 0, double Pf = 0, double Ps = 0, double Rf = 0, double Rs = 0, const double pi = 3.14159265) // with default arguments (= 0)
        : indicator(i), Pfirst(Pf), Psecond(Ps), Rfirst(Rf), Rsecond(Rs), pi(pi) {}
    ~Complex();
    void poltorect();
    void recttopol();
    static int inputfile();
};





#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "Complex.h"
using namespace std;


int Complex::inputfile()
{
    ifstream ComplexFile;
    ComplexFile.open("PolarAndRectangular.txt");
    string TextArray[3];
    string TextLine;
    stringstream streamline, streamfirst, streamsecond;
    while (getline(ComplexFile,TextLine))
        {
            streamline << TextLine;
            for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
            {streamline >> TextArray[j];}
            streamline.str("");
            streamline.clear();
            if (TextArray[0] == "r") 
            {
                streamfirst << TextArray[1];
                streamfirst >> Rfirst;
                streamsecond << TextArray[2];
                streamsecond >> Rsecond;
                cout << "Complex number in rectangular form is " << Rfirst << "," << Rsecond << endl;
                void recttopol();
                cout << "Complex number in polar form is " << Pfirst << "," << Psecond << endl;
            }
            else 
            {   
                streamfirst << TextArray[1];
                streamfirst >> Pfirst;
                streamsecond << TextArray[2];
                streamsecond >> Psecond;
                cout << "Complex number in polar form is " << Pfirst << "," << Psecond << endl;
                void poltorect();
                cout << "Complex number in rectangular form is" << Rfirst << "," << Rsecond << endl;
            }
            streamfirst.str("");
            streamfirst.clear();
            streamsecond.str("");
            streamsecond.clear();
        }
    ComplexFile.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}   


void Complex::recttopol()
{
     Pfirst = sqrt((Rfirst*Rfirst)+(Rsecond*Rsecond));
     Psecond = (atan(Rsecond/Rfirst))*(pi/180);
 }

void Complex::poltorect()
{
    Rfirst = Pfirst*(cos(Psecond));
    Rsecond = Pfirst*(sin(Psecond));
}



int main()
{
    Complex::inputfile();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to create an object of type `Complex`.

Make your `inputfile()` method nonstatic and do:

```
int main()
{
    Complex complex; // Object construction.
    complex.inputfile();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get an error 'unresolved external symbol "public thiscall Complex:~Complex(void)" (??1Complex@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function_main'. Do you know what this means?

Comment: @ChrisElwell You also forgot to implement your destructor: change `~Complex();` to `~Complex() {}` and this error will disappear.